# Change highlight color for TextInput control's selected text

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I have a Flex3 TextInput control, with white text on a black background.  I would like to change the style of highlighted text within the control to use black text on a white background (or something similar).  I would love to do this using Flex styles, however I'm comming up empty handed.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've chased this as well some time ago and came to a dead end.  What I found is this is a limitation hardcoded in the Flash player.  I'd love it if someone could prove me wrong, but I'm confident this is the case.  As the other poster noted, this is no longer an issue with the new Spark components.

Comment: How unfortunate.  The project I'm working on is slated to be upgraded to Flex 4 sometime in the future, our customers will have to wait till then.

Comment: I hear you.  This was a big source of frustration for me too.  At the time I was working on an app with a very dark theme, which made the highlighting impossible to see.

Comment: @WadeMueller, you are saying it is not an issue with the new Spark components. Do you mean, it is not an issue to change the highlighter color? Or text color under the highlighter? I am desperately searching for the answer for the second question. I want my text to change the color, while highlighted. It seems to be impossible event with Spark components. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

```
textinput.setStyle(“unfocusedTextSelectionColor”,”#00FF00″);
textinput.setStyle(“focusedTextSelectionColor”,”#00FF00″);
textinput.setStyle(“inactiveTextSelectionColor”,”#00FF00″);
```

You might need to place the code in a custom styleInitialized() method:

```
override public function stylesInitialized():void
{
    super.stylesInitialized();

    textinput.setStyle(“unfocusedTextSelectionColor”,”#00FF00″);
    textinput.setStyle(“focusedTextSelectionColor”,”#00FF00″);
    textinput.setStyle(“inactiveTextSelectionColor”,”#00FF00″);
};
```

For more details about setting styles see: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/SkinnableTextBase.html#style:focusColor

Good luck,
Rob

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for the response.  Unfortunately, I am stuck using the Flex 3 TextInput, and the styles you mention are only available in the Flex 4 spark implementation.

Answer (score 0):

With Flex 3, simply change your style to get the desired effect.

MXML:

```
<mx:TextInput
        styleName="{(whatever.isSomething() || whatever.isSomethingElse()) ? 'TextInputBlackOnWhite' : 'TextInputWhiteOnBlack'}"
        text="{whatever.value}"/>
```

Styles:

```
.TextInputBlackOnWhite
{
    borderSkin: Embed(source="assets/images/TextInput_BlackOnWhite.png", scaleGridLeft="2",scaleGridTop="2",scaleGridRight="19",scaleGridBottom="19");
    color: #000000;
}

.TextInputWhiteOnBlack
{
    borderSkin: Embed(source="assets/images/TextInput_WhiteOnBlack.png", scaleGridLeft="2",scaleGridTop="2",scaleGridRight="19",scaleGridBottom="19");
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```